# Variance of function

Tags: scala, covariance

```
sealed trait Sum[+A, +B] {
  def flatMap[A, C](f: B => Sum[A, C]): Sum[A, C] =
    this match {
      case Failure(v) => Failure(v)
      case Success(v) => f(v)
    }
}
```

Isn't it said that function parameters are contra-variant and the results co-variant? Why does the compiler say that A is in a contra-variant position? I am expecting compiler to complain that B is in a contra-variant position instead.

Can someone explain to me why this is so ? Feeling confused.

Comment: Isn't that because you are overloading `A` type parameter in the method definition? Try to define it this way: `def flatMap[C](f: B => Sum[A, C]): Sum[A, C]` and you will get an error.

Comment: Not sure why people upvote this comment. Even without overloading `A` *is* in contra-variant position. For a great explanation see this presentation: https://youtu.be/VZWLRepyNvo?t=1h5m57s

Comment: Apologies for the confusion i made. The original code snippet was def flatMap[AA >:A, C](f: B => Sum[AA, C]): Sum[AA, C] = ??? i wanted to show the non compiling version and edited on the fly. It should have been def flatMap[C](f: B => Sum[A, C]): Sum[A, C] =  ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you actually meant to write:

```
sealed trait Sum[+A, +B] {
  def flatMap[C](f: B => Sum[A, C]): Sum[A, C] = // No shadowing of A
    this match {
      case Failure(v) => Failure(v)
      case Success(v) => f(v)
    }
}
```

Take a look at `flatMap` again:

```
def flatMap[C](f: B => Sum[A, C]): Sum[A, C]
```

Let's rewrite it a bit:

```
def flatMap[C]: (B => Sum[A, C]) => Sum[A, C]
```

Let's build up the type from the inside out.

```
Sum[A, C]
```

`A` is a parameter to `Sum`, which is normally a covariant position.

```
B => Sum[A, C]
```

`Sum[A, C]` is the result of a function, which is normally a covariant position. These two combine, and you have `A` in a covariant position still.

```
(B => Sum[A, C]) => Sum[A, C]
```

`B => Sum[A, C]` is also the *parameter* of a function, so the *entire thing* is in contravariant position. Since `A` was in a covariant position before, the variances combine and `A` is now in a contravariant position.

Looking at `B`:

```
B => Sum[A, C]
```

Parameter of a function, which is normally a contravariant position.

```
(B => Sum[A, C]) => Sum[B, C]
```

The entire function is also the parameter to another function, so the contravariances cancel out and `B` is sitting in a covariant position.

You can also draw a nifty analogy. Look at the definition of a covariant and contravariant type parameter:

```
trait Co[+A]; trait Con[-A]
```

They look like positive and negative numbers, just a bit. Now, remember the rules for multiplication and signs you learned in elementary:

- `(+) * (+) = (+)`
- `(+) * (-) = (-)`
- `(-) * (+) = (-)`
- `(-) * (-) = (+)`

This is analogous to (if you squint a bit)

- `Co[Co[A]]` => `A` is in a covariant position
- `Co[Con[A]]` => `A` is in a contravariant position
- `Con[Co[A]]` => `A` is in a contravariant position
- `Con[Con[A]]` => `A` is in a covariant position.

Comment: Is there a mistake here? "Note now that A is a parameter to Sum, which is normally a covariant position." - contravariant?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify?

Comment: I thought parameters to a function are in contravariant position?

Comment: I meant to break down the type from the inside out, starting with `Sum[A, C]`, then `B => Sum[A, C]`, then `(B => Sum[A,C]) => Sum[A,C]`. I'll clarify that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: Typo at rewrite

Comment: I don't see any typo, and neither does my spellchecker :P

Comment: You copied and pasted the wrong lines, the rewrite didnt happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131455/discussion-between-htnw-and-user1677501).